# android wrap content container, make children colliding and set alignment to the right

Tags: android, layout

I want to make Layout with width wrap_content and inside it two children. First align to the parent left, second to the parent right. Children have to collide together and stretch parent width. This is what I have done:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:minWidth="160dp"
android:background="@android:color/black"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/waiting" />

<TextView
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/status"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:text="12:00 PM"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now children collide together, stretch parent, but second child (TextView#date) is not aligned to the right. I do not know how to do this.

Comment: if you are using constraint layout then set constraints for your views instead of gravity

Comment: Okay, I removed gravities. Second child (#date) has constraintLeft to collide with ImageView (to not overlap) and constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" but now it's centered. 

Main problem with second child to place it to the right and to not overlap with first child.

Comment: constraint them according to parent

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stretch to parent width, you should use match_parent, like so

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:minWidth="160dp"
android:background="@android:color/black"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/status"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="12:00 PM"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Working with LinearLayout and using gravity attributes is helpful

Comment: But unfortunately I cannot use match_parent in root container

Comment: can you tell me more about why you can't use match_parent ? 
LinearLayout , gravity and RelativeLayout can solve almost any layout. I'd like to assist

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use `ConstraintLayout`, then simply adjust a few constraints in your layout. To *dynamically* stretch the second child, set its width to `match_parent`, apply layout rules for its startOf and endOf, and set gravity to right or end in case it is stretched due to its parent's minimum width.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_background"
        android:minWidth="160dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/waiting"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12:00 PM"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="right|end"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/status"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Nice, TextView#Date is to the right, does not overlap with first child but one problem. If I set long text, the root container is not stretching, TextView gets breakline.

I do not have to use ConstraintLayout

Comment: Oh in that case then change `android:layout_width="0dp"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in your `date` view.